# How do I get my websites clip-path shape to not affect the rest of the website?

Tags: html, css

I started making a website and wanted to make a unique shape to go behind my logo and navigation bar. To do this I used clip-path code in my CSS which is new to me and my first time trying this. I am unable to get it to work though as there is either a big gap in between the nav bar and the text on the page if I use relative positioning or it will all be crammed at the top and be layered on top of each other if I use absolute positioning.
I cannot figure out how to get the effect I want. I left it with relative positioning at the moment as it is the closest I could get. Any help would be much appreciated.

```css
body {
  z-index: 1;
  display: block;
  min-width: 44em;
  max-width: 60em;
  margin: 0 auto;
  font-family: 'Times New Roman', Times, serif Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  background-color: rgb(76, 119, 175);
}


/*my logos code */

#logo {
  z-index: 1;
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}


/*the purple shapes code */

#purpleL {
  z-index: 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 961px;
  height: 80px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-color: rgba(64, 19, 85, 0.952);
  clip-path: polygon(100% 0, 100% 27%, 41% 28%, 0 47%, 0 0);
}

h2 {
  text-align: center;
}

.navbar {
  z-index: 1;
  color: rgb(119, 206, 201);
  text-align: left;
  padding: 0.25em;
  padding-left: 1em;
  float: left;
  width: 7em;
  top: 0px;
}

.navbar ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  position: relative;
  top: 2em;
}

.navbar li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0.25em;
  margin: 0.25em 0;
  position: relative;
  background-color: darkcyan;
}

#name {
  text-align: center;
}

.nav a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

nav a:link {
  color: black;
}

nav a:visited {
  color: purple;
}

nav a:hover {
  color: white;
}

nav a:active {
  color: blue;
}


/*my solid grey background to go behind everything */

#solid {
  z-index: -1;
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<div id="solid">
  <!--my logo-->
  <img src="images/cm designs.png" width="940" height="180" alt="cm designs" id="logo" />
  <div id="purpleL">
    <!--the div I used to mark where my purple shape is to go.-->
  </div>
  <nav>
    <ul class="navbar">
      <li><a href="index.html"> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="calander.html"> acnh calander </a></li>
      <li><a href="about.html"> about me </a></li>
      <li><a href="art.html"> art portfolio </a></li>
      <li><a href="contact.html"> contact </a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <h2> Home </h2>
  <p> Hello! My name is Christie Mattern and I am the creator of this website. I jsut wanted to start by saying thank you for checking out my website! I coded everything myself as well as created all the art for it. On here I have included an about me page
    for anyone looking to hire me, a contact page incase someone needs to get ahold of me. This could be becuase there is an issue with the website, about a job offer or because something changed with animal crossing and the calander needs adjusted.
  </p>
  <p>I also included a page for my art portfolio, I am a freelance artist and my art can be found there. I also designed a calander for the bigs and fish in the new Animal Crossing New Horizons game. I didn't like a lot of the apps and the wikis were not
    great. I am wanting to turn this into a full app and am in the process of doing so. For the time being though it is available here and may or may not stay here after the app is done.
  </p>
  <p> Again, thank you for checking out my website and I hope you like what you see!</p>
  <p id="footer">Christie Mattern &homtht; Fort Wayne, Indiana &homtht; isfsf</p>
</div>
```